# Want to get object of reference collection by _id in mongodb node.JS

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I want to get all detail of particular record by reference id collection.

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("586c8bf63ef8480af89e94ca"),
"createdDate" : ISODate("2017-01-04T05:45:26.945Z"),
"branch" : {
    "$ref" : "branchmst",
    "$id" : "5864ac80fa769f09a4881791",
    "$db" : "eviral"
    },
"__v" : 0
}
```

This is my collection record. I need to all detail from "branchmst" collection where "_id" is "5864ac80fa769f09a4881791".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your collection is an example of using manual references i.e. including one document's _id field in another document [DBref](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/database-references/#dbrefs). Mongoose can then issue a second query to resolve the referenced fields as needed.

The second query would be to use the aggregate method which has the **[`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/#pipe._S_lookup)** operator that will perform a left outer join to "branchmst" collection in the same database to filter in documents from the "joined" collection for processing:

```
MyModel.aggregate([
    { "$match": { "branch": "5864ac80fa769f09a4881791" } },
    {
        "$lookup": {
            "from": "branchmst",
            "localField": "branch",
            "foreignField": "_id",
            "as": "branchmst"
        }
    },
    { "$unwind": "$branchmst" }
])
```

You can also use the **[`populate()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-populate)** function in Mongoose given you have explicitly defined the refs in your Model definition i.e.

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var ObjectId = mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId;

// define the main schema
var mySchema = mongoose.Schema({
    createdDate: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
    branch: { type: ObjectId, ref: 'Branch' }  
})

// define the branch schema
var branchSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    address: String  
})

// compile the models
var MyModel = mongoose.model('MyModel', mySchema),
    Branch = mongoose.model('Branch', branchSchema);

// populate query
MyModel.find({ "branch": "5864ac80fa769f09a4881791" })
       .populate('branch')
       .exec(function (err, docs) {
           //console.log(docs[0].branch.name);
           console.log(docs);
       });
```

Answer (score 1):

provided you saved your branch.$id as type Schema Object.

```
 yourRecord.find({}).populate(branch.$id).exec(function(err, data){
  console.log(data)
})
```

Comment: What is "provideid"?

Comment: Its a variable name for the id you pass.if you want to find any particular document, otherwise just go ahead without id : providedid . It will populate for all the records

Comment: var objModel = require('../models/logModel'),

objModel.find(function (err, results) {
        if (err) {
            return res.send(500, { error: err });
        }

        results.find().populate(branch.$id).exec(function (err, data) {
            console.log(data)
        })
});

Is this right??

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132398/discussion-between-hardik-mandankaa-and-sac-dahal).